# css - fixed parent div showing 0.4px whitespace beneath content - cant fix it?

Tags: html, css

I've got this weird problem which it seems that i simply can't solve (so far). The weird thing is that I've done almost exactly the same layout before for a navigation-bar, which was succesful.

In my navigation bar i have a button (not an actual `<button>` but a `<div>` which acts like one through jquery) to the farthest right of it, which has a background color and expands on click. The problem is that in IE and some resolutions of Chrome as well, there's a little white stripe shown beneath this div. Further this makes the child div that expands beneath it have a little gap between the button in the navigation bar and it self. This might not matter to some people (or most), but it's driving me mad - especially considering that i've done it before and used almost the very same css.

The `<div>` (to be more precise, it's the "quick-download" div) is set to a height of 70px and line-height of 70px, and the same goes for its siblings (and some of them less). However, the parent div shows up as 70.4px in height, which is bugging me out. I've tried numerous "trial-and-error" solutions/attempts, but with no success at all.

EDIT:
An image of the problem can be seen here (i changed background to red to make it more apparent): https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtbGa.jpg

EDIT 2:
The white space beneath the quick-download div appears only to be showing in IE and Safari on my compute right now.

EDIT 3:
Link to website is removed as the problem is corrected and therefore no longer is useful.

Comment: can you make a picture i cant find it

Comment: @felixsturm i've added an image in the original post. You might have to zoom though, as it only is 0.4px :)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you mean the "Quick Download" button...

The height of the navigation bar is `75px` and the height of the button is `70px`, creating a 5px-tall gap.

The reason your navigation bar is `75px` is because your image on the left is `60px` tall with `margin-top: 15px;`. If you want the button to be flush with the bottom of the navigation bar, you can either increase the height of the button, reduce the `margin-top` of the `<img id="aktie-skat-logo" ...>`, or reduce the image's height.

The CSS in question:

```
#aktie-skat-logo {
    margin-top: 15px;
    display: block;
}
```

Comment: oh gosh sorry @santi ! That is my mistake. This was some old css i hadn't updated yet, and sadly isn't the problem. I'm at laptop which runs at less than 1600px browser resolution (is full hd screen though) and simply hadn't seen it, because it only changed above 1600px.

This is changed now though

Answer (score 0):

I've actually tracked the problem down my self - however, only after checking the problem across different browsers, after posting in here. The hint came in my old version of safari and IE, and didn't show in Chrome - which is consistent with "EDIT 2" in the original post. I found that some links we're 0.4px higher than others, but only 2/5 links.

The problem apparently stems from inserting a FontAwesome icon using the css `::after` selector to links that has "children" (subpages). After removing this or making these icons `position:absolute` the problem is solved.

As to why insering these using `::after` I have no idea. The `::after` element had `display:inline` so shouldn't have broken too much in my opinion.

I'm sorry that I might have wasted your time checking my problem and answering, but even though I found the solution my self, it was a help posting in here (wouldn't have found it otherwise). I hope this might help some other people at some point.